# Emacs freezes with ipython 5.0.0

Tags: ipython, elpy

My problem is Emacs with elpy, specifically with `(elpy-use-ipython)` in my init file.
When I try to open a python file, emacs freezes.

I desactivate `ipython` and emacs runs well. But I wanna use `ipython` because it is a great tool.

My OS is Arch Linux, recently (21/07/2016), ipython upgrades from version 4.2.0 to 5.0.0. The emacs version is 24.5.1.

Now, how I can fix this issue? How I can use `ipython` again?

Comment: Can you please provide some more detail? Can you give a recipe that shows what you mean, starting with `emacs -Q`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ipython`  5.0.0 by defautl uses [prompt_toolkit](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit) which is  really nice in a terminal but uses special characters for colors and completion that screws emacs display. Eventually it should be fixed but for now I have this in my `.emacs`:

```
  (setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython3"
    python-shell-interpreter-args "--simple-prompt --pprint")
```

and run `M-x run-python` to lauch the ipython interpreter wihtout `prompt_toolkit`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to Lompik's is to simply downgrade to ipython4. This might be better anyway, because --simple-prompt argument that lompik suggests removes many of the great features of ipython. For example, now you rely on elpy to do completions, and you can't have multi-line input

Comment: That's right. By the way, is this problem not fixed yet?

Comment: @cactus I can't seem to find one. If you do, let me know. Right now i'm struggling to stop elpy from spawning an unnecessary python process at startup. Save me.